# Which topics should be covered in a first course in Commutative Algebra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, schemes

Specially, if the aim is to learn algebraic geometry (more specifically, learning Scheme and variety theories and then Etale Cohomology to understand proofs of weil conjectures).

which topics MUST be covered in such a course? Which topics would be useful to cover but it's still OK  not to cover them if time does not permit?

Which textbook\online notes do you recommend for such a course?

Comment: Atiyah, McDonald: *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* (especially the exercises) can be a starting point. Notes by A. Gathmann, and J.S. Milne are also good (available from their homepages).

Comment: @Krish, I know those books already and gone through some of their chapters. my main question is on the TOPICS that would be relevant. and then comes the texts.

Comment: I can't think of any chapter from Atiyah & McDonald that you can skip if you want to start from books like Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*. On the other hand, this book does not cover topics like *flatness, differentials*. For that you need to look at other books, e.g. Matsumura, Eisenbud. Look at the book *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmatic Curves* by Qing Liu, Chapter 1. It contains some of the results from Commutative Algebra as prerequisite (be warned that Liu's book also contains good amount of Commutative Algebra that is scattered across the whole book).

Comment: I would consider Gröbner bases for calculation purposes and a CAS like Singular. There is a Singular Book by the inventors which is useful.